# Adding paper-item to paper-menu dynamically

Tags: jquery, ajax, polymer-1.0

I have a `paper-menu`:

```
<paper-menu id="city-menu"></paper-menu>
```

to which I am adding items using jQuery based on the results of an ajax return caused by typing into another field. That field is not important, but my success function for the ajax call is

```
      function (data) {
        if (data.success == 'true') {
          menuItems = '';
          $.each(data.data, function(index, city){
            menuItems += '<paper-item id="'+city.id+'">'+city.name+'</paper-item>';
          });
          $('#city-menu').html(menuItems);
          $('#city-menu').show()
        } else {
          $('#city-menu').hide()
        }
      }
```

but now that I have upgraded my Polymer components, this line no longer works:

```
$('#city-menu').html(menuItems);
```

that is, instead of the series of 'paper-item' cities I get a single div:

```
<div class="selectable-content style-scope paper-menu"></div>
```

(And, yes, I have verified `menuItems` is what I think it should be.) On the other hand, if I do something silly like

```
$('#city-menu').html('<h1>Hello World!</h1>');
```

then it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So inserting the whole menu at once rather than the items works. The success function for the ajax call in this case becomes:

```
      function (data) {
        if (data.success == 'true') {
          $('#city-menu').remove()
          menuItems = '<paper-menu id="city-menu">';
          $.each(data.data, function(index, city){
            menuItems += '<paper-item id="'+city.id+'">'+city.name+'</paper-item>';
          });
          menuItems += '</paper-menu>';
          $(menuItems).insertAfter('#city-id');
          $('#city-menu').show()
        } else {
          $('#city-menu').hide()
        }
      }
```

Which, surprisingly enough, works. Mostly.

Comment: Just curious, why not create custom polymer element that gets passed the city objects and in the <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{cities}}"><paper-item>{{item.name}}</paper-item></template>

Comment: Inexperience mostly.

Comment: I accidentally hit enter too soon...;) read the previous comment